# Use pregmatch to filter email providers

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to block all email providers except some of theme,

**PHP code**:

```
$hostings = "/@yahoo|@gmail|@msn/";
if(!preg_match($hostings, $email))
$stop .= "Invalid Email Provider";
```

Problem is, i can't use capital letters! for example i cant use this email:

```
Gmail.com
```

How i can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `/i` modifier to make your regex case-insensitive.

(You could also compare `strtolower($email)` against your regex.)

Finally, I suggest you hoist the `@` so you have `/@(yahoo|gmail|msn)/`.

Edit: Combined, your regex looks like this: `/@(yahoo|gmail|msn)/i`.

Comment: here: $hostings = "/@yahoo|@gmail|@msn/i";